# Command-line putty.exe SSH connection to capture output

Tags: ssh, vbscript, putty

I'm doing automated ssh login to Linux server from Windows machine. And it is done through `putty.exe` client.

```
Const WshRunning = 0
Dim UserName
Dim Passwrd

IP = "192.20.30.40"
UserName = "someuser"
Passwrd  = "somepass"

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
pcmd = "putty.exe -ssh" & " " & UserName & "@" & IP & " -pw" & " " & Passwrd & " -m ""commands.txt"""

Set exec = shell.Exec(pcmd)

Do While exec.Status = WshRunning
     WScript.Sleep 100 
Loop

Set pout = exec.StdOut
strOutput = exec.StdOut.ReadAll()

WScript.StdOut.Write(strOutput)
WScript.Echo(strOutput)
```

But I couldn't get the output of commands executed on Linux server. How can I get the out put of those Linux command at VBScript variable?

Some suggestion are there regarding Plink tool. But it didn't allow automated password based ssh.

Answer (score 0):

The `putty.exe` is a GUI application. It's intended to interactive use, not for automation. There's no point trying to redirect its standard output, as it's not using it.

For automation, use another tool from PuTTY package, the [`plink.exe`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). Plink is a console application, so you can read its standard output. Plink can the same set of command-line arguments as PuTTY. And it addition to those, you can also specify the command to be executed directly on its command line, instead of using separate command file (using `-m` switch).

---

*You have claimed that you already tried Plink and it did not work. That does not sound likely. Plink is internally identical to PuTTY. If you have problems with Plink, you have to give us more details. Show us what did you try and some log of that attempt.*